# Converting a dictionary to a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am having trouble with converting a dictionary to a string in python. I am trying to extract the information from one of my variables but cannot seem to remove the square brackets surrounding the information

```
for line in str(object):
    if line.startswith ('['):
        new_object = object.replace('[', '')
```

### Is there a way to remove the square brackets or do I have to find another way of taking the information out of the dictionary?

Edit:

in more detail what i am trying to do here is the following

```
import requests
city = 'dublin'
country = 'ireland'

info = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city +','+ country +'&mode=json')

weather = info.json()['weather']

fh = open('/home/Ricky92d3/city.txt', 'w')
fh.write(str(weather))
fh.close()
fl = open('/home/Ricky92d3/city.txt')
Object = fl.read()
fl.close()

for line in str(Object):
    if line.startswith ('['):
        new_Object = Object.replace('[', '')
    if line.startswith ('{'):
        new_Object = Object.replace('{u', '')

print new_Object
```

i hope this makes what i am trying to do a little more clear

Comment: Why are you looping over the `str(object)` version? You are now iterating over *individual characters*. What is the problem you are trying to solve here? Can you give us a sample `object` value and tell us more about your expected output?

Comment: And why not just loop over the dictionary *directly*? You can loop over the keys, the values, or the keys and values paired up.

Comment: Couldn't you use `str(yourdictionary)` to convert it to string?

Comment: You can easily access the JSON data directly from the list in `weather`. Eg, `print weather[0]['description']` currently prints `broken clouds`. But if you need to write it to a file & then read it back again you should write it and read it using the standard Python [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module.

Comment: Please include the expected output and the exact error message, if any.

Answer (score 3):

The object returned by `info.json()` is a Python dictionary, so you can access its contents using normal Python syntax. I admit that it can get a little bit tricky, since JSON dictionaries often contain other dictionaries and lists, but it's generally not too hard to figure out what's what if you print the JSON object out in a nicely formatted way. The easiest way to do that is by using the `dumps()` function in the standard Python `json` module.

The code below retrieves the JSON data into a dict called `data`.
It then prints the 'description' string from the list in the 'weather' item of `data`.
It then saves all the data (*not* just the 'weather' item) as an ASCII-encoded JSON file.
It then reads the JSON data back in again to a new dict called `newdata`, and pretty-prints it.
Finally, it prints the weather description again, to verify that we got back what we saw earlier. :)

```
import requests, json

#The base URL of the weather service
endpoint = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'

#Filename for saving JSON data to
fname = 'data.json'

city = 'dublin'
country = 'ireland'

params = {
    'q': '%s,%s' % (city, country), 
    'mode': 'json',
}

#Fetch the info
info = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
data = info.json()
#print json.dumps(data, indent=4)

#Extract the value of 'description' from the list in 'weather'
print '\ndescription: %s\n' % data['weather'][0]['description']

#Save data
with open(fname, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

#Reload data
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    newdata = json.load(f)

#Show all the data we just read in
print json.dumps(newdata, indent=4)

print '\ndescription: %s\n' % data['weather'][0]['description']
```

**output**

```
description: light intensity shower rain

{
    "clouds": {
        "all": 75
    }, 
    "name": "Dublin", 
    "visibility": 10000, 
    "sys": {
        "country": "IE", 
        "sunset": 1438374108, 
        "message": 0.0118, 
        "type": 1, 
        "id": 5237, 
        "sunrise": 1438317600
    }, 
    "weather": [
        {
            "description": "light intensity shower rain", 
            "main": "Rain", 
            "id": 520, 
            "icon": "09d"
        }
    ], 
    "coord": {
        "lat": 53.340000000000003, 
        "lon": -6.2699999999999996
    }, 
    "base": "stations", 
    "dt": 1438347600, 
    "main": {
        "pressure": 1014, 
        "humidity": 62, 
        "temp_max": 288.14999999999998, 
        "temp": 288.14999999999998, 
        "temp_min": 288.14999999999998
    }, 
    "id": 2964574, 
    "wind": {
        "speed": 8.1999999999999993, 
        "deg": 210
    }, 
    "cod": 200
}

description: light intensity shower rain
```

Comment: I should mention that this code no longer works as is because the api.openweathermap.org site now requires an API key, which can be obtained free upon registration. See their [FAQ](http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here (without seeing your dictionary) but if you have a string like `x = "[myString]"` you can just do the following:

```
x = x.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
```

If this isn't working, there is a high chance you're actually getting a list returned. Though if that was the case you should see an error like this:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x.replace("[", "")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

**Edit 1:**

I think there's a misunderstanding of what you're getting back here. If you're just looking for a csv output file with the weather from your api try this:

```
import requests
import csv

city = 'dublin'
country = 'ireland'

info = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city +','+ country +'&mode=json')

weather = info.json()['weather']
weather_fieldnames = ["id", "main", "description", "icon"]

with open('city.txt', 'w') as f:
  csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=weather_fieldnames)
  for w in weather:
    csvwriter.writerow(w)
```

This works by looping through the list of items you're getting and using a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write it as a row in the csv file.

**Bonus**

Don't call your dictionary `object` - It's a reserved word for the core language.

Comment: +1 for the bonus. Maybe it looks trivial, but it is very important to pay attention to the reserved words. It can lead to severe bugs.

Comment: I am trying to take information out of a JSON api. i have the variable saved as "   weather = info.json()['weather']   "
and saved the results as a text file. Then do a loop to remove the '[' brackets which appear at the start of the information but "  new_Object = Object.replace('[', '')  " doesnt affect it